# Object not rendering how I mapped it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

So I modeled an object and after trying to figure out how to apply multiple textures to the same item, I decided I would just edit the texture to accommodate. Unfortunately, while trying to add multiple textures I think I messed up my nodes. Here's some screen shots:

This is the problem: [image]

These are my compositing nodes: [image: Compositing Nodes]

These are my shader nodes: [image: Shader Nodes]

I wanted the table legs to have the iron texture, the top a light wood texture, and everything else the dark wood texture. I'd imagine this is probably a pretty basic issue, but I'm new and the most I've done with nodes is image displacements.

Comment: Is it possible you have two UV sets? Check in *Properties > Object data > UV*